# How may I add both ferrari and rollsroyce categories to my ArrayList<Product>

Tags: java, arrays

I'm developing an 'online shopping store' and I have a abstract Product class which contains general attributes and methods, inherited by subclasses which act as 'product categories', e.g. Phones.

I have another class called ProductDatabase which contains ArrayList to store Product objects.
In this class I have a method 'public put(Product)' used to provide the functionality for adding a product to the database.

In my main class I have 'public static ProductDatabase generateSampleDatabase() which initializes and returns a ProductDatabase object with the products.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZEwa.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQ1id.png

Comment: is your VehicleLuxury and VehicleSports the same type as Vehicle?

Comment: Please post your code in the question, not in an image

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your `ProductDatabase` hold a collection of `Vehicles` you can make it hold a generic type such as any object that implements a product interface.  `ArrayList<? implements Product>` is how you would declare this collection. Then you could declare your vehicle class as such: `public class Vehicle implements Product`

Now obviously this is dependant on your system design and how you think your object graph should look, but this is just a general idea.  Hope this helps